# Hadoop vs DDS vs ACE

Tags: hadoop, ace, distributed-objects, data-distribution-service

I am writing a report about distributed systems libraries for Java. But I can't see the difference between them. What is the difference between ACE vs Hadoop vs DDS? Can the three of them be used to develop a distributed application like a simple chat? Thanks!

Comment: This is somewhat of an odd selection of technologies, since they serve very different purposes. That makes it hard to compare them. How did you come to select these trhee? Also, ACE is written in C++ in the first place and the Java version does not seem to be complete and development has stopped (see [Java ACE](http://cvs.doc.wustl.edu/JACE/))

Comment: I surffed the web looking for alternatives to RMI and CORBA. And so I found those. But I am not so sure the uses of them in object distribution, which is the goal of this report.